# jqplot xaxis ticks are not rendered

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the below code to generate jqplot.

```
  var data = [["25 August 2002", 299.75],["02 September 2002", 1511.22],["02 October 2002", 1967.00],["01 November 2002", 2335.80],["02 December 2002", 2008.15],["02 January 2003", 4579.52],["02 February 2003", 5253.98],["07 March 2003", 5491.12],["01 April 2003", 8937.26],["08 May 2003", 16520.95],["01 June 2003", 13725.03],["01 July 2003", 22800.12],["11 August 2003", 34828.20],["01 September 2003", 48176.53],["01 October 2003", 57216.98],["01 November 2003", 45644.96],["01 December 2003", 50927.94],["01 January 2004", 51279.52],["01 February 2004", 41711.34],["01 March 2004", 49790.00],["01 April 2004", 49686.61],["01 May 2004", 40634.78],["22 August 2004", 16889.98],["01 September 2004", 41684.68],["29 June 2006", 151.55],["25 March 2008", 469.75],["17 July 2008", 159.90],["04 August 2008", 719.55],["11 December 2009", 94.00],["01 December 2010", 449.95],["01 April 2011", 449.95],["01 June 2012", 4529.40]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('DealerResp', [data],
            {
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                        label: 'Subs. Revenue',
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: 'R%.2f'
                        },
                        min: 0

                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        label: 'Period',
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: '%b-%Y'
                        },
                        pad: 0
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, it is not generating the xaxis ticks (i.e., dates). 
Yticks are coming fine.

Below are the scripts I have included.

```
<script src="/javascript/jquerylib/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquerylib/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/support/compositerpt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquerylib/jqplot/jquery-1.6.1.jqplot-1.0.0b2_r792.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquerylib/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/jqplot/jquery-1.6.1.jqplot-1.0.0b2_r792.min.css" />
<link href="/CSS/less/stealth.less" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have previously raised similar question, but I have not got any answers.

can somebody plss advise as soon as possible ???

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle of above so it can be easy for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am not able to create a new fiddle. The code is pretty as I gave. I just has the div in html with id="DealerResp"

Answer (score 0):

I am quessing by looking at your scripts' paths, which appear to be a bit disorganised, that them are the problem. Therefore, I say that you are not finding the `dateAxisRenderer` plugin which by default is under the `plugins` folder which is under jqplot `dist` folder in which the library comes.

Otherwise please build a jsfiddle. I would sugest you to use [the sample shown in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468936/613495), since there you do not need to edit scripts and just enter your codes and see if it works.